# jsf h:inputText and Double value

Tags: jsf

I use:

```
<h:inputText id="costsPerPallet" value="#{globalReportSelectionForm.palletCost}" size="5">
   <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00"/>
</h:inputText>
```

palletCost is a Double;

When entering a value of "1.00" and submit it is fine.
When I enter "1" and submit I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

What is a good way to put "1.00" before the submit. In the onblur javascript function?
Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine here on JSF Mojarra 1.2_14 and 2.0.2. So I think it's a bug in one of the ancient versions and that you need to upgrade your JSF version. You may also try to explicitly convert it as `Double` as follows.

```
<h:inputText converterId="javax.faces.Double">
```

Not sure if that works though. Upgrading your JSF impl to latest build is definitely worth it.

Comment: Thanks, I will upgrade JSF.

I'm using JBOss, Seam 2.1.2, Richfaces.  In the Seam folders I see jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar (
Mojarra JSF API Implementation 1.2_12-b01-FCS)

But: when deploying I only see jsf-facelets.jar (Implementation-Version: 1.1.15.B1)
I created my project using seam-gen

I will look into how to upgrade it to 1.12


For the moment I will leave out:

    <f:convertNumber pattern="0.00"/>

This causes the error.

Comment: Could it be this is re-introduced in very recent JSF versions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54553332/fconvertnumber-on-double-classcastexception

Comment: Looks like the same problem yes.